# How do you force search engines to show main categories of your site in snippet?

Tags: html, seo

If you search "reddit" or "youtube" or many other sites in a major search engine, you will obtain the title of the site, the meta description, and links to its major categories right below such as 'music', 'funny' etc.

Does anyone know how to manipulate your page to get the search engine to index your pages with links that you want displayed below your site description? Is there a meta tag I am missing or a tag I should add to these links?

Comment: Yes, become popular and it'll happen automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Google, there is no way to force this:

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334